# Creating a line of best fit error for linear regression

Tags: python, linear-regression

I am struggling to create a line of best fit for my plot.

The error I keep obtaining is: operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes [original->remapped]: (75,)  and requested shape (1000,)
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRoCP.png)

```
# Plot Curve Fit
x_fit = np.linspace(0,21,1000)
y_fit = x_fit

# using the predict model on features to get the z-fit

z_fit=model.predict(features)

fig=plt.figure(figsize=[15,15])

ax1=fig.add_subplot(2,2,1, projection='3d')
ax1.set_xlabel('x', c='r', size=12)
ax1.set_ylabel('y', c='r', size=12)
ax1.set_zlabel('z', c='r', size=12)
ax1.plot3D(x_fit, y_fit, z_fit, 'gray')
ax1.view_init(0,90)
ax1.scatter3D(xdata, ydata, zdata, c=zdata, cmap='jet')
```

Comment: I tried changing `x_fit = np.linspace(0, 21, 1000)` to `x_fit = np.linspace(0, 21, 100)` and it works. You can just change the number of points to 100.

Comment: And FYI, the `xdata`, `ydata`, and `zdata` arrays I've defined each have a shape of `(100,)`.

Answer (score 0):

let `xdata`, `ydata`, and `zdata` each have a shape of N. And the goal is to plot a scatter plot using `xdata`, `ydata`, and `zdata`.

If you are plotting a figure using `x_fit`, `y_fit`, and `z_fit`, then `x_fit`, `y_fit`, and `z_fit` should also have a shape of N to ensure consistency and avoid broadcasting errors.